# Getting linking error for i2c_smbus_read_byte()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, ubuntu-18.04, i2c

I want to perform, read write operation on /dev/i2c-0 in sama5d27_som(arm_cortex_A5) board. Therfore I have used the i2c_smbus_read_byte()in my program. I have installed the following packages libi2c-dev and i2c-tools in my ubuntu18.04. But while cross_compiling, I got the following error.

```sh
~/guru/projects/i2c$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc main.c 
/tmp/ccW1Pk9X.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `i2c_smbus_read_byte'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gp@guru-hp:~/guru/projects/i2c$
```

Here is the source code. Please have a look and help me on this. Thanks

```c
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <sys/ioctl.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
 #include <i2c/smbus.h>

 int main(void)
 {
     printf("Wellcome to device programming.\n");
     printf("Enter i2c port no : ");
     u_int8_t prt = 0;
     scanf("%c",&prt);
     char pth[18] = {0};
     sprintf(pth,"/dev/i2c-%c",prt);
     int fd = open(pth,O_RDWR);
     if(fd > 0)
     {
         printf("%s has been opened\n",pth);
         int rt_ctl = 0;
         for(int i=0;i<=60;i+=10)
         {
             if(!i)
             {
                 printf("     ");
                 for(int i=0;i<=0xf;i++)
                 {
                     printf("%x  ",i);
                 }
                 printf("\n");
             }
             printf("%.2d: ",i);
             for(int j=0x0;j<=0xf;j++)
             {

                 rt_ctl = ioctl(fd,I2C_SLAVE,i+j);
                 if(rt_ctl < 0)
                 {
                     printf("-- ");
                     //perror("ioctl() failed due to : ");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     rt_ctl = i2c_smbus_read_byte(fd);
                     if(rt_ctl < 0)
                     {
                         printf("-- ");
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         printf("%02x ",j);
                     }
                 }
             }
             printf("\n");
         }
         close(fd);
     }

 }
```

Comment: I think you are missing the `-li2c` option to link in the libi2c library.

Comment: I did the same, but got the same error again.

Comment: gp@guru-hp:~/guru/projects/V4/source_codes/drivers/GIT/i2c/dev_i2c$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc  -li2c main.c
/tmp/cc3zVp1r.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to `i2c_smbus_read_byte'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gp@guru-hp:~/guru/projects/V4/source_codes/drivers/GIT/i2c/dev_i2c$

Comment: You might need to put the `-li2c` option after the .c files on the command line. Also, you'll need the `libi2c-dev:armhf` package. There may be other problems because the `libi2c.so*` files also need to be present on the embedded device unless you link the libi2c library statically into the executable.